# Witha Valid Certificate: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

Recently we have changed the certificate in server and we cannot access a simple https petition i Android; the certificate is NOT self-signed, but signed by a Trusted Validator;

our code in Android is:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URL url = null;
        StringBuffer buffer = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://........com/test");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        String stringResult = buffer.toString();
        return stringResult;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution? Also have a cert here which is valid and iOS says that everything is fine but Android fails with the exception you described above.